# Should the matrix4 comparison method be consider the floating point comparison logic?

Tags: c++, matrix, floating-point, comparison

I made a Matrix class. and added some methods for matrix calculation.
I met some problems related with floating point operation.
First time, I made a eqaul method like below:

```
bool
FloatMatrix4::operator ==(const FloatMatrix4& rhs) const
{
  if (this == &rhs)
    return true;
  return (matrix[0][0] == rhs.matrix[0][0] &&
          matrix[0][1] == rhs.matrix[0][1] &&
          matrix[0][2] == rhs.matrix[0][2] &&
          matrix[0][3] == rhs.matrix[0][3] &&
          matrix[1][0] == rhs.matrix[1][0] &&
          matrix[1][1] == rhs.matrix[1][1] &&
          matrix[1][2] == rhs.matrix[1][2] &&
          matrix[1][3] == rhs.matrix[1][3] &&
          matrix[2][0] == rhs.matrix[2][0] &&
          matrix[2][1] == rhs.matrix[2][1] &&
          matrix[2][2] == rhs.matrix[2][2] &&
          matrix[2][3] == rhs.matrix[2][3] &&
          matrix[3][0] == rhs.matrix[3][0] &&
          matrix[3][1] == rhs.matrix[3][1] &&
          matrix[3][2] == rhs.matrix[3][2] &&
          matrix[3][3] == rhs.matrix[3][3]);
}
```

Under case, it returned wrong answer.

```
m1[4][4] = 
 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
 2.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
 3.000000, 1.100000, 1.000000, 1.000000,
 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000`

m2[4][4] = 
1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
2.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
3.000000, 1.100000, 1.000000, 1.000000,
4.000000, 0.000000, -0.000000, 1.000000
```

I expected `m1` and `m2` are same, because `m2` was made with 2-times inverted `m1`.

So I though matrix comparison operation should include floating pointer comparison algorithm.
like a `AlMostEquals()` or `floatHardCompare()` method.

```
bool matrixCompare(const FloatMatrix4& m1, const FloatMatrix4& m2)
{
  return (
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[0][0], m2.matrix[0][0], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[0][1], m2.matrix[0][1], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[0][2], m2.matrix[0][2], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[0][3], m2.matrix[0][3], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[1][0], m2.matrix[1][0], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[1][1], m2.matrix[1][1], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[1][2], m2.matrix[1][2], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[1][3], m2.matrix[1][3], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[2][0], m2.matrix[2][0], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[2][1], m2.matrix[2][1], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[2][2], m2.matrix[2][2], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[2][3], m2.matrix[2][3], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[3][0], m2.matrix[3][0], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[3][1], m2.matrix[3][1], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[3][2], m2.matrix[3][2], ALMOST_ZERO)==0 &&
    floatCompare(m1.matrix[3][3], m2.matrix[3][3], ALMOST_ZERO)==0);
}
```

`ALMOST_ZERO = 0.0000000001` or `DOUBLE_EPSILON`

I'd like to ask that.
Generally, are the `matrix4` implementations considered floating point comparison logic in the graphics library or graphic engine (include game engine)? or not?

Anyone has more good idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Comment: I wanna know , how did other framework or engine solve this issue? like a unity or unreal engine, or cairo.. and etc... If i use floating point comparison logic in matrix comparison, it would make performance issue.

bool  FloatMatrix4::operator == (const FloatMatrix4& m2)
{
 return matrixCompare(*this, m2);
}